# How can I verify a form with an SQL databse?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, forms

So I have an SQL database that has a table for accounts and info, and another one for storing comments on articles. I Have a form for submitting comments and it works just fine, but I wanted to implement a feature to prevent spam and non registered accounts. I was trying to find a way to make the following code work so that it would call upon my account table and check to see if the `username` section matches what was entered in the form.

I want it to check through my `username` column on the table to see if what was entered in the box is actually in the database as well, that way if it hasn't been registered it won't submit.

My problem I keep running into is that I try this

```
<?
         if ($_POST['Uname']==`username`){
         $strSQL="INSERT INTO `comments`
         (`name`,`comment`,`date`,`#`) VALUES
         ('".$_POST['Uname']."','".$_POST['Comment']."',
         '".$_POST['Date']."','".$_POST['#']."')";
         }
             else{
             echo "Username invalid";
             }
}
?>
```

But when I do this it thinks that "username" is what the username needs to be in order to submit properly.

I do not want every username to need to be "username" in order for them to submit, I just want it to check through my `username` column to see if what was entered is one of the registered usernames in the SQL column.

Im not sure if this is possible, or if I am making any sense, but this is my first post on this site and I would appreciate any help I could get.

Full code is below

```
<?
     if ($_POST['Enter']=='Enter'){ 
     $con = mysql_connect
     ("sql***.*******.com","*****","*******");
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db("*********",$con); //My login
     $test2=$_GET['ID']; //Ignore
     $_POST['#']=$test2; //Ignore
     $sql="Select * from `Articles` and `Accounts`"; //For pulling data
     mysql_query($strSQL,$con);

         if ( ? == ? ){  //What should go here?
         $strSQL="INSERT INTO `comments`
         (`name`,`comment`,`date`,`#`) VALUES
         ('".$_POST['Uname']."','".$_POST['Comment']."',
         '".$_POST['Date']."','".$_POST['#']."')";
         }
             else{
             echo "Username invalid";
             }
 }
?>
```

*Edit*

So after making the changes needed, should my previous code end up like this?

```
 <?
 if ($_POST['Enter']=='Enter'){
 $con = mysql_connect
 ("*******","********","*****");
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db("*****",$con);
 $test2=$_GET['ID'];
 $_POST['#']=$test2;
 $username = $_POST['Uname'];
 $sql = "Select `id` from `Accounts` where `username` = $username";
 mysqli_num_rows($sql,$result);
 $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
 echo $result;

    if ($row_cnt!=''){
    $strSQL="INSERT INTO `comments`
    (`name`,`comment`,`date`,`#`) VALUES ('".$_POST['Uname']."',
    '".$_POST['Comment']."',
    '".$_POST['Date']."',
    '".$_POST['#']."')";
    }
        else{
        echo "Username invalid";
        }
 }
```

?>

Comment: you're mixing different mysql apis here, you can't do that.

Comment: you have ticks `\`` in this if ($_POST['Uname']==`username`) which is also failing and your `$username` is also failing. Too many errors in this.

Comment: *"So after making the changes needed, should my previous code end up like this?"* - No. I strongly suggest that you visit the php.net website, look up those mysql functions and stick to the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously what you doing is not correct, as of now you are putting condition as :

```
if ($_POST['Uname']==`username`)
```

which means you saying any user who's name is 'username' should be able to comment, but what you want to achieve is, any user who is valid user and is exist in db should be able to comment. So for that you should write a select sql to check the user, :

```
$username = $_POST['Uname'];

$sql = "select id from yourusertable where username = $username";
```

then,

perform

```
  mysqli_num_rows
```

to check if you get anything greater than zero. If yes, then allow to submit comments.

Comment: Would the edits I made above be the proper application of this?

Comment: No that's not right. What is $rows = $query->num_rows;. I do not see $query in your code.

Comment: That was left over from when I checked another site on the application of mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Now when i submit it echoes back "Resource id # 8"

Comment: I believe I have formatted it a bit better now, but I am still not seeing how I set the parameters for the mysqli-num-rows

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply the check that only `loggedIn` user can `comment`. So if the user will not exist in `users` table it will not be `loggedIn` nor can `comment`.